# Why are my mango's leaves are getting brown and curling?

Tags: plant-health, diseases, leaves, tree-care, mango

I started to grow a mango tree from seed 2 years ago in a pot. The mango tree is outside on my balcony when temperatures are above 15° celsius otherwise it stays inside where temperature is 20° celsius. The first winter inside, the leaves started to get a little brown on the edge but I didn't pay much attention as it was not expanding since I noticed it. This winter it started again on new leaves but this time it got quite worse (leaves were getting brown again on a much larger area and began to curl) and I tried to find some solutions online but I didn't find any clear identification.

I tried to spray some fungicide (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bordeaux_mixture) on leaves and trunk that's why my mango tree has blue stains. Now, it seems that these brown stains don't expand anymore but I wanted to know if someone ever faced similar  problem.

Am I watering it too much / not enough ? Too much sunlight / not enough ? Lack of nutriments ? Fungus attack?

Thanks for your help
[image]
[image]